# while loop to infinity when the input of a cin is a 'dot'

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, cin

I am having trouble using the cin method to acquire a variable. When the input is a number there is no problem, but when it is a special character like a dot [.], 
the whileloop loops into infinity.
What am I doing wrong?

```
cout << "What is your race" <<endl<<"1.Human\n2.troll\n3.zombie"<<endl;
    cin >> *race;
    while(*race<1||*race>3)
    {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Wrong choice"<<endl<< "What is your race" <<endl<<"1.Human\n2.troll\n3.zombie"<<endl;
    cin >> *race;
    }
```

I searched for the answer and i should have to flush the buffer but i don"t get how to do it. I'm rather new with c++. Thanx

Comment: @Rps: no it isn't. If `race` was of type `int`, then `*race` would be an error, the compiler would reject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `race` an char, then you will be able do to:

```
while (*race < '1' || *race > '3')
```

which is probably what you want to achieve.

Explanation:

When you `cin >>` into an int, it converts given ASCII string to integer value. `.` doesn't have an integer meaning, so it isn't read into `race` and `failbit` is set - further >>s are no-op, until you clear them. However, if you `cin >>` into `char` and compare it with other `char`s (well, their ASCII codes, actually), you will be able to check it without troubles.

Comment: The solution may be what is actually wanted (although it doesn't address all of the issues), but the explication is incorrect.  When you `cin >>` into an an `int`, and the input stream contains a `'.'`, `failbit` is set in `cin`, and all further input becomes a no-op until this is cleared.  (Of course, he also needs to remove the offending character(s); `cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );` is probably most appropriate for this.)  And your solution will go into an endless loop if there is any other error on `cin`, like end of file.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you are generally correct, but wrong in last statement - you _won't_ get EOF from `stdin`.

Comment: Since when?  The standard certainly supports it, and I get it with all of the implementations I know.  What should happen when `cin` encounters end of file, if not an end of file condition?

Comment: Erm, right, my bad. However, other possible ways to do it won't give you support for EOF, there is one I know of (as !file.eof() is not considered good practice): `std::getline()`. Following your comment, I should tell him "don't use `cin >>`, use `std::getline()`!" - but it doesn't seem to make much sense in this case, as it's not "how to handle EOF" question, but "how to handle `.`" one.

Comment: Input will fail at end of file.  Just test for failure (`if (cin)`), and **after** failure, check whether it was due to end of file, and do whatever is appropriate.  (Given that he's prompting, and obviously expecting keyboard input, rather than input redirected from a file, throwing an exception on end of file could be appropriate.)  More generally, if not using `getline, you should check for failure in the loop (`while (!cin...)`), and either clear the error before condinuing, or abort the input in case of end of file.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution besides the one accepted is to clear the cin's `failbit` and ignore the last input like below:

```
cout << "What is your race" <<endl<<"1.Human\n2.troll\n3.zombie"<<endl;
cin >> *race;
while(*race<1||*race>3)
{
    // Clears the state of cin to be in good state
    cin.clear();
    // Ignores the last input read so that it's not read back again
    cin.ignore();
    system("cls");
    cout << "Wrong choice"<<endl<< "What is your race" <<endl<<"1.Human\n2.troll\n3.zombie"<<endl;
    cin >> *race;
}
```

Comment: It's not the `badbit` that you're clearing, but the `failbit`.  (But `cin.clear()` clears them all, and is the correct solution.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the correction. Edited the answer for those who're interested in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This example exactly reproduces your problem:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    while (i < 1 || i > 3)
    {
        std::cin >> i;
    }
}
```

Here's what happens: When `operator>>` fails to read an integer (e.g. when you type a dot and press enter), whatever you typed *stays* in the stream, including the newline character.
So in the next iteration of the while loop the next input is already there and since it's not a valid integer, the loop can never break.
You need to make sure that, when `operator>>` fails, you empty the stream and clear all the error flags that got set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    while (i < 1 || i > 3)
    {
        if (!(std::cin >> i))
        {
            // clear streams internal error flags
            std::cin.clear();
            // ignore what's left in the stream, up to first newline character
            // or the entire content, whichever comes first
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems  with your code.  The first is that you don't
verify that your input has succeeded; the correct condition for the
`while` should be:

```
while ( !cin || (*race < 1 || *race > 3) )
```

As written, if the input fails (which is what is happening when you
enter a `'.'`, supposing that `race` has type `int*`), then `*race`
contains its previous value, whatever that was.

The second is that if you do get an error from `cin`, you don't clear
it.  Once the stream is in an error state, it stays that way until you 
explicitly clear it.  If `cin` has failed, you need to execute:

```
cin.clear();
```

somewhere in the loop.

The third is that if `cin` fails, you don't extract the character which
made it failed, so that after clearing the error status, you need to
extract it.  Given the way you've structured your dialog, you probably
want to ignore everything until the end of the line:

```
cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );
```

You may want to do this even if `cin` didn't fail, either in the loop
(if entered because of the `*race < 1 || *race > 3` condition), or in
case of success.  Alternatively, you may want to shift to reading lines,
and ensure that the line only contains whitespace after the character
you're interested in.

This last solution is the one I would adopt, since it handles pretty
much all of the above problems.  So my code would look something like:

```
//  return -1 on error in input,
//  throw exception on (unexpected) end of file
int
getRace( std::istream& source )
{
    std::string line;
    if ( !std::getline( source, line ) ) {
        throw std::ios_base::failure( "Unexpected end of file" );
    }
    std::istringstream tmp( line );
    int results;
    return tmp >> results >> std::ws && tmp.get() == EOF
        ? results
        : -1;
}

//  ...
int race = -1;
while ( race < 0 ) {
    std::cout << "What is your race\n"
                 "1. Human\n"
                 "2. Troll\n"
                 "3.  Zombie\n" << std::flush;
    race = getRace( std::cout );
    if ( race < 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Wrong choice" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that by inputting through a line, you avoid any problems with
resetting format errors, skipping erroneous input or resynchronizing in
case of error.